# Is there any way to design the font color of the last row of text?

Tags: css, linear-gradients

I want the styles as follow image:
expectation omission style

[image]

The styles and relative code that I made as follows: image: https://gyazo.com/171b8cf4785c2c0e629828982ac4cb69
relative code:
.msg-content
              position: relative

```
          @media(max-width: 767px)
            display: block
            padding-top: 10px
            padding-bottom: 10px

          @media(min-width: 768px)
            &:after
              position: absolute
              height: 100px
              content: ""
              top: 0px
              left: 0px
              right: 0px
              bottom: 0px
              background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #FFFFFF 48px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6) 48px, rgba(255, 255, 255,0.6) 58px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 58px)
```

Comment: Without wrapping the specificied text in a element ....NO.

Answer (score 1):

There are the `:last-child` and `:last-of-type` pseudo-classes. Adapted to your example:

```
div > p:last-child { color:#c5c5c5; }
```

or

```
div > p:last-of-type { color:#c5c5c5; }
```

However, this solution  presupposes that you split the text into lines beforehand ( at least the final line ). It appears that you are actually after a css pseudo-element in the vein of [`::first-line`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3A%3Afirst-line) that would apply styles to the *last* line of an element. Unfortunately, afaik, no such beast exists.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but that the text is call back with JSON data. I can't control the text.

Answer (score -1):

```
your html:-

<div>
<p>Something your text........</p>
<p>Something your text........</p>
<p class="special">Something your text........</p>
</div>
```

your css:-

```
p {
    color:#000;
}
p.special{
   color:#c5c5c5;
}
```

If you want to different color same line then you can use `<span></span>`.
html:-

```
<div>
<p>hello<span>world</span></p>
</div>
```

css:-

```
p{
  color:black;
}
span{
  color:red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but the text is call back with JSON data, I can't control the text with more p tags